# Solving the integral $\int_{z^2}^{\infty}\sqrt y e^{-\frac{y}{2}}(y-z^2)^{\frac{n}{2}-2}dy$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

While solving a problem related to distribution of random variables, I got stuck in this integral:

$\int_{z^2}^{\infty}\sqrt y e^{-\frac{y}{2}}(y-z^2)^{\frac{n}{2}-2}dy$

Please anyone give some hint about how to solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you substitute $y = (tz)^2$ you obtain $$I_n(z)=2z^{n-1} \int_1^{+\infty} t^3 (t^2-1)^{n/2-1} \exp\left( -\frac{ t^2z^2}{2} \right) \operatorname d x$$For small values of $n$, this seems related to the error function